# Laravel Passport pass additional value to return statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I have following IssueToken Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use DB;
use App\Client;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

trait IssueTokenTrait
{
    public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = "")
    {
        $params = [
            'grant_type' => $grantType,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id, // php artisan passport:client --password
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'scope' => $scope
        ];

        $request->request->add($params);

        $mail = $request->username;
        $clientTable = DB::table('clients')->where('email', $mail)->first();
        $client = Client::findOrFail($clientTable->id);
        $clientID = $client->id;

        $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

        return Route::dispatch($proxy);         }
}
```

Which Returns a token type an expire in and Access token and a refresh token.

Now I want to add the Client_id to the reponse how do I do that?